# Logical Equivalence - OR gates and implication

Tags: logic, equivalence, implication

I'm currently answering a logical equivalence question and would like confirmation of the rule I used at one point as it is not in the list of laws, presumably because it's "something you should just know".

Part of my working is `(NOT(p) OR NOT(q)) OR r == (NOT(p) OR r) OR (NOT(q) OR r)`
to then be simplified later to `(p implies r) OR (q implies r)`

Constructing a truth table and also constructing it through LogicWorks I believe that the two are logically equivalent, but what is the law I used on the first part? Associative?

**EDIT:**
 I realize that the `LHS` and `RHS` may be logically equivalent but could I have missed a step out?

Answer (score 1):

```
p => r = (¬p) ∨ r 
q => r = (¬q) ∨ r
(p => r) ∨ (q => r) = ((¬p) ∨ r) ∨ ((¬q) ∨ r)
(p => r) ∨ (q => r) = (¬p) ∨ (¬q) ∨ r ∨ (¬q) ∨ r ∨ (¬p) ∨ r∨r -- distribution
(p => r) ∨ (q => r) = (¬p) ∨ (¬q) ∨ r -- elimination of duplicates
```